# Console use 30% cpu on the server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, console-application

I have developed a complicated console app that do the following:

- I insatll the console app as window service.
- In this console app i created a web api host self site.
- In addition in the background of the console i open socket connection with
  another computer.

Now when i run this app(not as windows service) in VS everything works good and the app use less than 2% cpu.

When i install this app on the server it use at least 20% cpu and somtimes even 30% cpu..

Now i can't understand where is the problem..
Anyone can suggest me how can i check what exactly "eat" so much cpu??

Comment: Is that 30% of one core? or an entire core? or...? But: reason would suggest that the problem lies in your service boilerplate...

Comment: It is 30% of the all cores.. what is boilerplate?

Comment: the utility code added to make it work as a windows service (or more generally: the utility code you add to make it work under any particular framework). Sounds like a tight loop somewhere.